# OR operator in Django filter creates duplicates

Tags: python, sql, django

when I print `Brand.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=keyword)|Q(tag__name__icontains=keyword))`, it yields two objects as opposed to my expectation. It should be only one.

My models.py is like

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True)
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

When I print `Brand.objects.filter(name__icontains=keyword)` and `Brand.objects.filter(tag__name__icontains=keyword)` seperately, each one yields only one same object. But when I merge these two queries, it yields duplicates. I found out `.distinct()` solves this problem but I wanna know why. Looking forward to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the or condition that results in duplicates, it is the fact that you are filtering on a related model with a `ManyToManyField`. This means that the query will look like:

```
SELECT brand.*
FROM brand
LEFT OUTER JOIN brand_tag ON brand_tag.brand_id = brand.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tag ON tag.id = brand_tag.tag_id
WHERE brand.name LIKE %keyword% OR tag.name LIKE %keyword%
```

You thus will `JOIN` on the tag model, and if multiple tags match the keyword, then that brand will be repeated that many times in the `QuerySet`.

If you thus would have filtered with `.filter(tag__name__icontains=keyword)`, you would have gotten duplicates as well.

---

> **Note**: There is a [**`django-taggit`** package [GitHub]](https://github.com/jazzband/django-taggit) to work with content that contains tags. This might be better than implementing your own tag system.

Comment: Thank you I will look around django-taggit! By the way when I print `.filter(tag__name__icontains=keyword)`, it yields only one object unlike you said. Am I doing something wrong? I don't know much about SQL. Or does it take place when there exist **multiple tags** that share a common keyword?

Comment: @Gianna: if both the `name` of the brand matches and one (or more) tags, it will also yield duplicates.

Comment: @Gianna: yes, it creates duplicates when you search for a keyword for which *multiple* tags *match* with the keyword.